# JavaFX Abnormally Closing Alert Returns Incorrect Result

Tags: java, javafx, dialog, modal-dialog, javafx-8

I have created a JavaFX `Alert` object that returns unexpected results when calling `showAndWait`.  The code below illustrates the behavior I am observing:

```
package myPackage;

import java.util.Optional;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert.AlertType;
import javafx.scene.control.ButtonBar.ButtonData;
import javafx.scene.control.ButtonType;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        launch();
    }

    private static boolean isYes(final Optional<ButtonType> result) {
        return (result.isPresent() && result.get().getButtonData() == ButtonData.YES);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        final Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.CONFIRMATION,
            "This is a test", ButtonType.NO, ButtonType.YES);
        System.out.println(isYes(alert.showAndWait()) ? "Yes" : "No or Closed");
        System.out.println(isYes(alert.showAndWait()) ? "Yes" : "No or Closed");
    }

}
```

When I run the above application, two dialogs are shown.  Click "Yes" on the first dialog, then close (by clicking the "x" in the upper right corner) the second.  By taking the above steps, I expect that the application would print the following:

> Yes
>   No or Closed

However, what I am actually seeing printed is:

> Yes
>   Yes

The [Dialog documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Dialog.html) states that an "abnormal closing condition" (such as clicking the small "x" in the upper-right corner) will "attempt to set the result property to whatever value is returned from calling the result converter with the first matching ButtonType."  Given the context of this statement, I interpreted "matching ButtonType" to mean a ButtonType that either (direct quote from the documentation):

> 1. The button has a ButtonType whose ButtonBar.ButtonData is of type ButtonBar.ButtonData.CANCEL_CLOSE.
> 2. The button has a ButtonType whose ButtonBar.ButtonData returns true when ButtonBar.ButtonData.isCancelButton() is called.

Is my interpretation of the documentation incorrect, or is this a bug in JavaFX?  Regardless of why this is not working as I expect, is there any way I can force "abnormal closing conditions" to return `ButtonType.NO` in this case?

Comment: I noticed that if I call `alert.setResult(null)` between the two calls to `alert.showAndWait()`, it works as documented (the result of the second call is then `ButtonType.NO`).  Is there ever a case where `isPresent` is false for an `Alert`?

Comment: `isPresent` would return false (AIUI) if you set a result converter on the alert that mapped the `NO` button to `null`. As for your main question, this looks like a bug.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be a bug. `showAndWait` never claims to clear the `result` property (In fact this may even be the desired behavior to allow the user to specify a default result in case no valid input is specified...).

Comment: @fabian I agree the documentation for `showAndWait` doesn't claim that, but if you read the documentation for `Dialog`, it does.  On this dialog, `ButtonData.NO.isCancelButton()` is true, which meets the second criteria.  Therefore, according to my reading of the documentation, "abnormally closing" the dialog should ALWAYS populate result with `ButtonType.NO`.  I have confirmed that cancelling prior to selecting the "Yes" button does in fact return `ButtonType.NO` as the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is yet another bug in JavaFX.  I have reported it to Oracle, and it was assigned Bug ID [JDK-8173114](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8173114).  As a work-around, I simply added the following line to the constructor(s) of my subclass of JavaFX `Alert`:

```
setOnShowing(event -> setResult(null));
```

The above work-around seems to work for `Alert`, `ChoiceDialog`, and `TextInputDialog`.

Answer (score 0):

Above workaround does not work with java 8 & win 10. But this works:

```
    Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.CONFIRMATION);
   // alert.setOnShowing(event -> alert.setResult(null));
    alert.setTitle("Delete similar files?");
    ButtonType okButton = new ButtonType("Yes", ButtonBar.ButtonData.YES);
    ButtonType noButton = new ButtonType("No", ButtonBar.ButtonData.NO);
    ButtonType cancelButton = new ButtonType("Cancel", ButtonBar.ButtonData.CANCEL_CLOSE);
    alert.getButtonTypes().setAll(okButton, noButton, cancelButton);
    Optional<ButtonType> choose = alert.showAndWait();
    // String text = new String("");
    // if (choose.get() != null)
       // text = choose.get().getText();
    // if (text != null && (text.equals("YES") || text.equals("Yes")))
    if (choose.get() == okButton){
```

Comment: I'm confused by this answer.  Creating a new `Alert` object every time you show a dialog wouldn't exhibit the behavior described in the question.  It is also unclear whether the commented out code is significant.  To improve this answer, please explain *how* the accepted answer is misbehaving in your case, and remove all commented-out lines if they are not necessary to make your solution work.